# Apereo CAS like identity provider of Azure AD, it's possible?

Tags: azure, cas, saml-2.0, azure-active-directory

It's possible to configure Apero CAS and Azure AD for Azure can delegate its user authentication to CAS ?

CAS became an idp.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by an IdP. CAS already IS an IdP.

If you need CAS to support SAML 2 Web SSO so it can be integrated with Azure AD, yes it's possible. More info at https://github.com/Jasig/cas

If you need CAS to support WSFED so it can be integrated with Azure AD, no it's presently not possible but can be done via something like Apache Fediz. cxf.apache.org/fediz This is potentially on the roadmap for the project.

Comment: Yes, I need CAS to support SAML 2 but with the last stable version (4.1), it doesn't seem actualy supported (cf. doc https://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/protocol/SAML-Protocol.html)

Comment: Yes. SAML2 Web SSO is presently available in 4.3 SNAPSHOTs. You will find the docs here: https://jasig.github.io/cas/development if you want to experiment